# Not able to view S3 bucket created from lambda function using python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I have created an S3 bucket using below code. The bucket got created but I'm not able to see the bucket in S3 console. What could be the reason? I used root user.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
try:
    if my_region == 'ap-south-1':
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name, CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'ap-south-1'})
    print('S3 bucket ' + bucket_name + ' created successfully')
except Exception as e:
    print('S3 error: ',e)
```

Comment: You might have to wait a couple of seconds for it to show up, you may be looking in the wrong account.

Comment: @luk2302 I created it by logging in as root user from lambda function. When I use the same root user to check S3 console I'm not able to see the bucket.

Comment: Are you sure that your code actually created the bucket? It would not if my_region != 'ap-south-1', for example. Are you sure the credentials used by your code actually correspond to the same AWS account that you're viewing in the AWS console? Also, [don't use account root credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html), especially in a Lambda function.

Comment: @jamod - The bucket got created, when I try to run the same code again it gives me an error stating bucket already exist. Yes the credentials corresponds to root account.